# Detecting phone numbers using sapi?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I am currently using sapi 5.4 and I want to detect a phone number which is sure of 10 digits from 0-9 what is the best way to specify in grammar file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple [sapi-format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) grammar ruleset that defines a rule that has 7-10 digits:

```
<rule name="phoneno">
  <phrase min="7" max="10">
    <ruleref name="digit" propname="digit"/>
  </phrase>
</rule>

<rule name="digit">
  <l>
    <p val="0">0</p>
    <p val="1">1</p>
    <p val="2">2</p>
    <p val="3">3</p>
    <p val="4">4</p>
    <p val="5">5</p>
    <p val="6">6</p>
    <p val="7">7</p>
    <p val="8">8</p>
    <p val="9">9</p>
  </l>
</rule>
```

This also sets up semantic properties so you can build the phone number by walking the semantic properties tree.